# Create Spark DataFrame from list row keys

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hbase, rdd

I have a list of HBase row keys in form or `Array[Row]` and want to create a Spark `DataFrame` out of the rows that are fetched from HBase using these RowKeys.

Am thinking of something like:

```
def getDataFrameFromList(spark: SparkSession, rList : Array[Row]): DataFrame = {

  val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
  val mlRows : List[RDD[String]] = new ArrayList[RDD[String]]

  conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "dev.server")
  conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181")
  conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent","/hbase-unsecure")
  conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "hbase_tbl1")

  rList.foreach( r => {
    var rStr = r.toString()
    conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_ROW_START, rStr)
    conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_ROW_STOP, rStr + "_")
    // read one row
    val recsRdd = readHBaseRdd(spark, conf)
    mlRows.append(recsRdd)
  })

  // This works, but it is only one row
  //val resourcesDf = spark.read.json(recsRdd) 

  var resourcesDf = <Code here to convert List[RDD[String]] to DataFrame>
  //resourcesDf
  spark.emptyDataFrame
}
```

I can do `recsRdd.collect()` in the for loop and convert it to string and append that json to an `ArrayList[String` but am not sure if its efficient, to call `collect()` in a for loop like this.

`readHBaseRdd` is using `newAPIHadoopRDD` to get data from HBase

```
def readHBaseRdd(spark: SparkSession, conf: Configuration) = {
    val hBaseRDD = spark.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat],
      classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable],
      classOf[Result])

    hBaseRDD.map {
      case (_: ImmutableBytesWritable, value: Result) =>
          Bytes.toString(value.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf"),
                                            Bytes.toBytes("jsonCol")))
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `spark.union([mainRdd, recsRdd])` instead of a list or RDDs (mlRows)

And why read only one row from HBase? Try to have the largest interval as possible.

Always avoid calling `collect()`, do it only for debug/tests.

Comment: Yes, I want to read more rows from HBase, but how do i do batch reading if my row keys are not ordered? For Eg. my keys are `["aab", "aad", "rrt", "rre", "ssa", "ssb" and so on..]`. In short how to give such row keys in the `SCAN_ROW_START` and `SCAN_ROW_STOP` ?

Comment: Well if you have an array of max 10 prefixes and each one has 100k values for example, it should be fine. But not an array of 10k prefixes with a few results each. In the later case you need to redesign your table/rowkey.